# prompting a user when leaving page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onbeforeunload

On my page I have a combobox called cbOrderSpareCustomer.
By default the selected index is set to 0.

when the user changes it, I consider the page containing data and when the user decides to leave the page I want to prompt him to let him know data will be lost.

I have seen many posts about this but I'm very new to javascript so I could use some help.

I understand I have to use:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload= function() { return "Custom message here"; };
</script>
```

But how do I make it work with the combobox?

like `if cbOrderSpareCustomer.selectedIndex > 0 then prompt else just continue.`

I also want to prevent it from showing the prompt on each postback.

I would like to see an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to make this work

1. Add `onchange` attribute to the combobox on serve side using the code:
     `<select id="cbOrderSpareCustomer" onchange="setDirty()">`
2. Define your javascript as below

   `var isDirty = true;

   function setDirty() {
       isDirty = true;
   }
   window.onbeforeunload = function () {
       if (isDirty) {
           return confirm('Your unsaved changes will be lost');
       }
   }`

Comment: You have set me in the right direction. 
My solution: function setDirty() {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                return 'The data will be lost if you leave this page!'
            }
        }

Answer (score 2):

You get on client side the drop down list, and check the index, your code will probably be as:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload= function() 
    { 
        if(document.getElementById('<%=cbOrderSpareCustomer.ClientID%>').selectedIndex > 0)
        {
            return "Custom message here"; 
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    if (document.getElementById('cbOrderSpareCustomer').selectedIndex > 0) {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure')) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in asp.net the client side id is not rendering the same, also the confirm is return true/false, not need for extra return, and is not nessesary in this case, you just return the string and the browser ask you with better question (to leave or stay from page, not with yes/no). (I am not add -1 as competitor to answers)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
        if ($("select[name='cbOrderSpareCustomer'] option:selected").index() > 0) {
            return 'Your data will be lost.';
        }
    });
</script>
```

You don't want else return true or it will still prompt (at least, IE prompts)

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
function setDirty() {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                return 'The data will be lost if you leave this page!'
            }
        }
</script>
```

With the attribute onCange="setDirty()" added to the dropdownlist.

Thanks all for helping!